# Discrete Math and Sets and subsets question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let Universe be {1,2,3,4,5,6}

If A = {1,2,3,4} then |A| = 4, and from this we can see that A is an element of U(universe), but can someone explain to me why {A} is NOT an element of U? I'snt the curly braces just saying "elements of A"?

Comment: $A$ is not an *element* of $U$ [if "being an element of" means : $\in$]. $A$ is a *subset* of $U$, i.e. $A \subseteq U$.

Comment: Okay i see where you go with this

Comment: Then you'll have to name the textbook, because that's a very non-standard usage of the word "element." @Joe

Comment: Grimaldi is my textbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correction: $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ is **not** an **element** of $U$: rather, $A$ is a ***subset*** of $U$. $1\in A, 1\in U, ....., $4 \in A, 4\in U$.

Now, $\{A\} = \{\{1, 2, 3, 4\}\}$ is neither an element of $U$, nor is it a subset of $U$. It contains exactly *one element*: $A$.

$A$ is a four-element set: the set containing $1, 2, 3,$ and $4$.
$\{A\}$ is a one-element set: the set whose *single* element is the set $A$.

Comment: If i changed my universe to {1,2,3,4,5,6,{1,2,3,4}} would it then be an element of U?

Comment: Yes, Joe. Then A would be an element of $U$.

Comment: But {A} is still not an element of U unless my universe was {1,2,3,4,5,6{{1,2,3,4}}}?

Comment: Exactly. You'd have to make that change.

Comment: You're welcome, Joe!

Answer (score 2):

There is no element $\{A\}=\{\{1,2,3,4\}\}$ in $U=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Notice too that $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$ is not an element of $U$ either. If it were, $U$ may look like $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,\{1,2,3,4\}\}$. The elements of $U$ are $1,2,3,4,5,$ and $6$.